# How to prevent a class in one package from importing any of the classes in another package?

Tags: java

I have a challenge about importing situations in java and I searched many resources but I didn't figure it out.

How to prevent a class in one package from importing any of the classes in another package?

**Not: I can not use maven or gradle & I can not change class access modifier, they should be public**

## Problem Example

### My Project Structure

```
-src
  -main 
    -firstpackage
      -A.java
    -secondpackage
      -B.java
    -thirdpackage
      -C.java
```

## A.java consist of

```
package main.firstpackage;


import main.secondpackage.B; // In compile time, this statement should give error 
import main.thirdpackage.C; // Its okey

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(); // In compile time, this statement should give error 
        C c = new C(); // Its okey 
    }
}
```

## B.java consist of

```
package main.secondpackage;

import main.firstpackage.A; // Its okey
import main.thirdpackage.C; // Its okey

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); // Its okey
        C c = new C(); // Its okey
    }
}
```

## C.java consist of

```
package main.thirdpackage;

import main.firstpackage.A; //Its okey
import main.secondpackage.B; //Its okey

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(); //Its okey
        B b = new B();//Its okey
    }
}
```

B class should not be imported from A (When a person try to import B class in A class, It should give error in compile time) on the other hand A class should be imported and C class should access  all other classes(A and B) ?

I tried many things, especially with java 9 modules but I didn't figure it

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: In package of B class, there are the technologies I use (spring, eclipselink, elasticsearch, kafka etc.), and in package of class C, I have common data classes that can be used in both package class of A and package class of B. I want to make package of class A technology independent, this class will only contain pure java code.

Comment: If secondpackage is in a separate module, that module’s descriptor can control which modules are allowed to access secondpackage.

Comment: @VGR thanks for your commenting, if I sperate them to the different modul, it would be wonderful but I can not do it because CI/CD process prevents it. The CI\CD process deeply couple to the project package structure

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a jar for each package, which you can certainly do. This is really a classpath question: What should be on the classpath and what shouldn't be? If you want classes in package A not to be able to access classes in package B, don't include them on the classpath at compile or runtime.

Comment: I don't know many things about including and, excluding to the classpath but I'll search for it and try to do this, this weekend. thanks for clues @cyberbrain, vgr, controlaltdel

Comment: You mention you cannot use Maven or Gradle, so it may be difficult to set up, but this seems like something that [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/use-cases) can enforce (though only at test time, not compile time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searched many resources, package structure or class depend checking is not possible as effectively for the compile or run time but in test time, ArchUnit can use for it but do not forget only test time.

Answer (score 0):

With your limitations you will have to put `A` and `main.firstpackage` into a separate project that does not depend on the other stuff. The compiler will never protect you from that kind of dependency within the same project.